# What is the right way to run compilation of a language like c++ in text editors and show outputs to the text editor?

Tags: plugins, command-line, compilation, ide, text-editor

I am curious to know how hackable text editors like atom and IDEs like eclipse and netbeans run compilations of programming languages in its application and show outputs inside the application.

Do the text editors/IDEs invoke the compiler like we do inside a command line (without having to display the command line GUI) to compile the files and then pipe the output to its built-in command line?

How is it really done?

Thanks in advance.

edit: I would like to know the procedure that those IDEs and text editors take to perform compilations and display outputs to the built-in/plugin terminal. I'm not asking because I don't know how to compile the code I wrote in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Atom editor have the appropriate plug-ins.

[terminal](http://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus) - the launch of the terminal directly from the atom editor.

[c++ compiler](http://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler) - compile and run c++ within atom editor.

Comment: I know there are plugins for them, but what I'm asking is 'what is the exact procedure that those plugins take to compile those languages. In case they are using an external compiler (perhaps that's already in your development environment, hence 'external' to the IDE/text editor), how do they invoke those compilers and output the results to the plugin terminal?'.